# Exposing Mahout recommender as a web service

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm building an asp.net application that should recommend items to users. I decided to use Mahout for its popularity but I now want to expose Mahout recommender as a web service so I can use it in my web app or any mobile apps that could be developed later.

In Mahout Documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation) , I found this

> A Mahout recommender can also be run as an external server, which may
>   be the only option for non-Java applications. It can be exposed as a
>   web application via org.apach.mahout.cf.taste.web.RecommenderServlet,
>   and your application can then access recommendations via simple HTTP
>   requests and response. See above, and see the javadoc for details.

What should I do in order to be able to expose mahout as a web service ? I don't have any knowledge in this field or in Java servlet but I writes Java SE. Can you help ?

Note : I don't want to use Hadoop as I'm not going to deal with millions of users and also this is my graduation project not a commercial product.